# matplotlib: Convert between linewidth points and transAxes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In many situations, I find it convenient to place square axes on a figure so that I can easily work in `transAxes` units without having to worry about the aspect ratio of the figure. However, one problem I'm having is that when you draw a line, the linewidth extends `lw/2` points in either direction from the path. This is the normal, expected behavior, of course, but it causes the problem that if I'm trying to inscribe something into some axes (and use all the space in the bounding box), the lines will clip on the edge of the axis. I can set `clip_on=False`, but that just makes it so that the figure I was trying to inscribe in the axis exceeds the boundaries of the axes. My question is this - how do I transform between the "linewidth" spec (in points) and the `transAxes` units, so that I can compensate for the additional length/width of the shapes?

I've worked up a simple MWE that should demonstrate what I mean:

```
"""
MWE demonstrating the cliping of linewidths that are inscribed in axes.
"""
from __future__ import division
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show, savefig
from matplotlib.pyplot import Circle
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

# Make a figure
(fig_w, fig_h) = (7.5, 2.5)
cdpi = 150
fig_aspect = fig_h/fig_w
fig = figure(1, figsize=(fig_w, fig_h), dpi=cdpi)

# Helper functions to center the circles
get_w_from_h = lambda h: h*fig_aspect
get_b_from_h = lambda h: (1-h)/2
get_l_centered = lambda left, span, w: left+(span-w)/2

# Left circle 1 - The line at the center shows that lw is the same number of pixels no matter 
# what transform you use.
l_h = 0.25
l_w = get_w_from_h(l_h);        l_b = get_b_from_h(l_h)
l_l = get_l_centered(0, 1/3, l_w)
l_box = [l_l, l_b, l_w, l_h]

lcax = fig.add_axes(l_box)
lclw = 2.0
lcirc = Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.5, lw=lclw, color='#FF3932', fill=False, transform=lcax.transAxes)
lline = Line2D([-0.5, 1.5], [0.5, 0.5], lw=lclw*4, color='#FF3932', 
             dashes=[5,1e-14,1e-14, 5], clip_on=False, transform=lcax.transAxes)
lcax.add_patch(lcirc)
lcax.add_line(lline)
lcax.axis('off')

# Left Circle 2
l_h2 = 0.75
l_w2 = get_w_from_h(l_h2);      l_b2 = get_b_from_h(l_h2)
l_l2 = get_l_centered(0, 1/3, l_w2)
l_box2 = [l_l2, l_b2, l_w2, l_h2]

lcax2 = fig.add_axes(l_box2)
lcirc2 = Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.5, lw=lclw, color='#b20500', fill=False, transform=lcax2.transAxes)
lline2 = Line2D([0.1, 0.9], [0.5, 0.5], lw=lclw*4, color='#b20500', 
             dashes=[1e-14,5,5, 1e-14], transform=lcax2.transAxes)
lcax2.add_patch(lcirc2)
lcax2.add_line(lline2)
lcax2.axis('off')


# Middle circle
m_h = 0.9
m_w = get_w_from_h(m_h);        m_b = get_b_from_h(m_h)
m_l = get_l_centered(1/3, 1/3, m_w)
m_box = [m_l, m_b, m_w, m_h]

mcax = fig.add_axes(m_box)
mclw = 4.0
mcirc = Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.5, lw=mclw, color='b', fill=False, 
               clip_on=False,
               transform=mcax.transAxes)
mcax.add_patch(mcirc)
mcax.axis('off')

# Right circle 1
r_h = 0.75
r_w = get_w_from_h(r_h);        r_b = get_b_from_h(r_h)
r_l = get_l_centered(2/3, 1/3, r_w)
r_box = [r_l, r_b, r_w, r_h]

rcax = fig.add_axes(r_box, zorder=1)
rclw = 2.0
rcirc = Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.5, lw=rclw, edgecolor='k', facecolor='#4E4E4E', 
               fill=True, transform=rcax.transAxes)
rcax.add_patch(rcirc)
rcax.axis('off')

# Right circle 2
r_h2 = 0.5
r_w2 = get_w_from_h(r_h2);      r_b2 = get_b_from_h(r_h2)
r_l2 = get_l_centered(2/3, 1/3, r_w2)
r_box2 = [r_l2, r_b2, r_w2, r_h2]

rcax2 = fig.add_axes(r_box2, zorder=2)
rcirc2 = Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.5, lw=rclw, edgecolor='none', facecolor='#BBBBBB', 
               fill=True, transform=rcax2.transAxes)
rcax2.add_patch(rcirc2)
rcax2.axis('off')

savefig('ClippingMWE.png', transparent=True, dpi=cdpi)
```

This generates this figure:
[image: Clipping figure]

Based on the comparison in the left circle, it seems like the linewidth is always the same number of pixels no matter what axis it is placed in (which makes sense). The center circle is what I'd like the circles to all look like (no clipping), but of course the circle is actually slightly wider than I wanted it to be. The circle on the right shows where the clipping box acts relative to the line. Clearly there's no problem inscribing *filled* circles in the axes.

While I would also be interested in knowing if there's a flag or something I could set to draw the line on a certain side of the path (e.g. draw the line on the *inside* of the path rather than centered on the path), I'm primarily interested in how to convert from `lw` to `transAxes` units, because I have essentially the same problem when trying to calculate the amount of space I need to accommodate a font of a given size.